# In which direction the port has to be opened?

Tags: windows, port, file-sharing

I've two systems and I want to transmit some XML files from one to the other.

My systems:
- MGMT Server
- Client Server

If my PowerShell Script runs on the MGMT Server and should be able to connect to the client server and take some files from there over FileSharePort (SMB -> Port 445) - in which direction the port has to be open?

I am right that ins enough to open it from MGMT to the Clientserver?

I'm sorry if this question may sounds stupid, I'm from the software department and I'm not really good in network technics.

I'm really thankful for any kind of advise.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: You'll need to investigate any and all firewalls running on, and those between, your management server and the client for their policies. *Typically* adding rules to allow traffic **from a source** (from  the mgmt server) **to a destination** (the correct port on the client) is sufficient, as most firewalls will automatically allow bidirectional traffic once the connection has been initiated. Some firewalls may need additional rules to specifically permit egress traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

The *source* of the request will be the MGMT server, and the *destination* of the request will be the Client server, so the direction of the request will be **MGMT -> Client**.

Most firewalls will automatically allow *related connections*, so if the MGMT server initiates a connection that is allowed by the firewall, related connections that are opened in the reverse direction will automatically be allowed.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Ill accept the answer when I can.